# Additional variables for "Places" dirs?

Tags: unity, nautilus, places

I know that I can edit ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs file to modify the locations of the various directories in nautilus' "places" list. I've even found that I can remove items from the list. Are there any other items that can be added to the list though? For example is there a way to list two directories that use the "documents" icon?

This is my known list of variables from the user-dirs.dirs file...

```
XDG_DESKTOP_DIR
XDG_DOWNLOAD_DIR
XDG_TEMPLATES_DIR
XDG_PUBLICSHARE_DIR
XDG_DOCUMENTS_DIR
XDG_MUSIC_DIR
XDG_PICTURES_DIR
XDG_VIDEOS_DIR
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found the documentation on this: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/saucy/man5/user-dirs.dirs.5.html

Looks like that's the final list.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site. Thanks for posting an answer but please don't use answers to ask further questions. If this serves as an answer to your question, then [accept it](http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers) and if it doesn't, please [edit] your original question instead.

Comment: Anyone know where to add to the recognized list or if that's even possible?

Comment: @DanZimney why not simply use bookmarks?

Comment: @muru Bookmarks are fine, but I'd really like to have more control over the "Places" section. I've found that after a restart any items that are removed from user-dirs.dirs replace themselves, which is unfortunate.

I don't use my Pictures, Music, Videos dirs and I'd like to remove the extra clutter. Might just have to use find an alternative to the Nautilus file manager... or put up with it.